# Enter the year and the number of weeks, return the corresponding Monday start time,

Tags: java, java-time, java.util.date, java.util.calendar, java.time.instant

The code looks like this:

```java
LocalDate.of(year,1,1).with(WeekFields.of(Locale.ENGLISH).weekOfWeekBasedYear(),weekNumber).with(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)
```

But when I count 49 weeks for this year, which is 2023, time always returns to 2023-11-27, and I actually think it should return 2023-12-04.

I was very confused and therefore I did a lot of tests

Finally, I let the program output the first week of the year,

When I use LocalDate.of(2023, 1, 1), the output is 2022-12-26
But When I use LocalDate.of(2023, 1, 2), the output is 2023-12-04

I began to understand the design. For this reason, I had to use java.util.Calendar for this function

My question is is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: with 365 days in a year, there isnt really 49 weeks in a year?

Comment: Can you be more clear on what you are trying to do?

Comment: Yes, the point is that Monday of Week 49 should be 2023-12-04, not 2023-11-27 @experimentunit1998X

Comment: You can try what is the return date of this code
```java
LocalDate.of(2023,1,1).with(WeekFields.of(Locale.ENGLISH).weekOfWeekBasedYear(), 1).with(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)
```
It should return 2023-01-02, not 2022-12-26
@experimentunit1998X

Comment: `LocalDate.ofYearDay(2023, 1).plusWeeks(49).with(TemporalAdjusters.previous(DayOfWeek.MONDAY))` == `2023-12-14` (in `yyyy-MM-dd` format)

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. Thank you. I may have been confused about the solution.

Comment: I think that's right, too
```java
LocalDate.of(2023, 1, 1).plusWeeks(49).with(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)
```
Do not use TemporalAdjuster.previous methods.
@MadProgrammer

Comment: be aware that week numbering depends on **location** (not [only] on language) - using `Locale.ENGLISH` is a bit strange here... different result expected when using `Locale.UK`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation of weekOfWeekBasedYear:

> Week one(1) is the week starting on the getFirstDayOfWeek() where
> there are at least getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() days in the year. If
> the first week starts after the start of the year then the period
> before is in the last week of the previous year. For example: - if the
> 1st day of the year is a Monday, week one starts on the 1st - if the
> 2nd day of the year is a Monday, week one starts on the 2nd and the
> 1st is in the last week of the previous year

If you put the year as LocalDate.of(2023,1,1) it counts it as the last week of last year since the first day of this year is a sunday (not monday)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which makes me understand where to start calculating the number of weeks.